# KDE - Plasma - Arrange windows vertically

Tags: kde, plasma5

I have two 28" 4k monitors. One is horizontal in front of me. The second is oriented vertically to the side. I am looking for a way to organize the open windows in the vertical monitor. For example, I would like a shortcut that takes all windows in the vertical screen, and arranges them vertically (equal height for each window and maximum screen width). Or a shortcut that takes all the windows in the horizontal screen, and distributes them horizontally (equal width for each window and maximum screen height).

I tried two tiling tools, [Exquisite](https://github.com/qewer33/Exquisite) and [Bismuth](https://github.com/Bismuth-Forge/bismuth), but neither seems to be right for me. Mainly because they don't seem to work well on two screens.